# Using Spark JDBC and Avatica to read records from a table in Apache Druid

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, druid, apache-calcite

I am trying to create a Dataframe in Spark that would contain all records from a table in Apache Druid and I am doing this using JDBC. Druid seems to be using the Calcite-Avatica JDBC driver (mentioned [here](https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/querying/sql.html#jdbc)).

```py
    df = spark.read.format('jdbc').option('url', 'jdbc:avatica:remote:url=http://172.31.5.20:8082/druid/v2/sql/avatica/').option('driver', 'org.apache.calcite.avatica.remote.Driver').option('dbtable', 'mytable').load()
```

But I am getting the following error

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o456.load.
: java.sql.SQLException: While closing connection
    at org.apache.calcite.avatica.Helper.createException(Helper.java:39)
    at org.apache.calcite.avatica.AvaticaConnection.close(AvaticaConnection.java:156)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRDD$.resolveTable(JDBCRDD.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRelation.<init>(JDBCRelation.scala:115)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcRelationProvider.createRelation(JdbcRelationProvider.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:341)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:239)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:227)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:164)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "rpcMetadata" (class org.apache.calcite.avatica.remote.Service$CloseConnectionResponse), not marked as ignorable (0 known properties: ])
 at [Source: (String)"{"response":"closeConnection","rpcMetadata":{"response":"rpcMetadata","serverAddress":"ip-172-31-5-234.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal:8082"}}
"; line: 1, column: 46] (through reference chain: org.apache.calcite.avatica.remote.Service$CloseConnectionResponse["rpcMetadata"])
    at org.apache.calcite.avatica.remote.JsonService.handle(JsonService.java:142)
    at org.apache.calcite.avatica.remote.JsonService.apply(JsonService.java:229)
    at org.apache.calcite.avatica.remote.RemoteMeta.closeConnection(RemoteMeta.java:78)
    at org.apache.calcite.avatica.AvaticaConnection.close(AvaticaConnection.java:153)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "rpcMetadata" (class org.apache.calcite.avatica.remote.Service$CloseConnectionResponse), not marked as ignorable (0 known properties: ])
 at [Source: (String)"{"response":"closeConnection","rpcMetadata":{"response":"rpcMetadata","serverAddress":"ip-172-31-5-234.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal:8082"}}
"; line: 1, column: 46] (through reference chain: org.apache.calcite.avatica.remote.Service$CloseConnectionResponse["rpcMetadata"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException.from(UnrecognizedPropertyException.java:61)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnknownProperty(DeserializationContext.java:823)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer.handleUnknownProperty(StdDeserializer.java:1153)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.handleUnknownProperty(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1589)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.handleUnknownVanilla(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1567)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:294)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer._deserializeOther(BeanDeserializer.java:189)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:161)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsPropertyTypeDeserializer._deserializeTypedForId(AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.java:130)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.deserializeTypedFromObject(AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.java:97)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeWithType(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1178)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.TypeWrappedDeserializer.deserialize(TypeWrappedDeserializer.java:68)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4014)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3005)
    at org.apache.calcite.avatica.remote.JsonService.decode(JsonService.java:131)
    at org.apache.calcite.avatica.remote.JsonService.apply(JsonService.java:227)
    ... 20 more
```

Does anyone know what could be the cause for this and how do I fix this? It seems that this seems to be an issue with the Avatica driver where it gets a json object with an unrecognizable field

I am using the driver `org.apache.calcite.avatica:avatica-core:1.17.0` and have added the jar file to my `spark.jars` property. I am using Druid 0.19.0 and Spark2.

*Edit*: I checked the source code for the Avatica JDBC framework and the constructor annotated as `@JsonCreator` expects a property called `rpcMetadata` in the json object being deserialized. Source code is [here](https://github.com/apache/calcite-avatica/blob/d56fcd004c68ca89c7e6aed2a86d46a9cb74f885/core/src/main/java/org/apache/calcite/avatica/remote/Service.java#L1946).

Answer (score 0):

Use below library & try again.

`"org.apache.calcite.avatica" % "avatica" % "1.8.0"`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but that didn't help. I am getting the exact same error message.

Comment: Ok, I have created build.sbt and tested it's working in scala.. how are you using in python to import this library ?

Comment: I downloaded the jar from maven central and added it to the `spark.jars` configuration parameter. I then wrote that single line in a zeppelin notebook and got the error. I saw the source code and found that the `@JsonCreator` constructor expects a field called `rpcMetadata` which is why I don't understand why this error is being thrown.

Comment: @thisisshantzz  Facing same issue, any suggestions here would be great help. Thanks in advance.